# Python - Replace slashes in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I've got a csv file that has around 100 rows. Some of the cells in the 100 rows have filepaths like:

```
C:\\\\Users\\\Simon\\\\Desktop\\\\file.jpg
```

I want to open the csv file in python and change only the rows that have triple-slashes and convert them to a single backslash. Here is my code so far:

```
import csv

with open('myCsvFile', 'rb') as csvfile:
    SysIndexTwo = csv.reader(csvfile)

for allRows in SysIndexTwo:
  if '\\\\' in allRows:
    writer.writerows(allRows.replace('\\\\', '\\'))
```

Tried the suggestions and get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SIPHON2.py", line 7, in <module>
    for allRows in SysIndexTwo:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
simon@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ python SIPHON2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SIPHON2.py", line 7, in <module>
    for allRows in SysIndexTwo:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You've got four slashes, not three, in your iteration.

Comment: You clearly haven't reasearch this at all, since you keep editing your question. See documention on with statement, files, and escaping special characters.

Comment: You have to intend the last three rows of your code, outside the `with` statement, the file is automaticly closed

Comment: You have at least three different problems here: the error message is the one Steinar and Henry explained; not being clear about whether you have 3 or 4 backslashes makes it impossible to write correct code; then not using raw strings makes it very hard to write (and read) code even when you count properly. Just fixing one of those three problems doesn't magically fix the other two; you need to fix all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to indent your actual processing. Right now, you drop out of the context manager (the `with` statement where you define your CSV reader) before you try to use it. Thus, you get the "IO operation on closed file" error because the context manager closed the file when you left it.

You want this:

```
with open('myCsvFile', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile) # Simple names are good, esp. in small scope!

    for row in reader: # Indent me!
        pass # Do stuff here.
```

The `with` statement is handy for automatically closing files (among other things) for you. However, this means that any work you do that requires the file you're using *must* be done before you leave the block, because once you leave, the file is closed!

The csv reader doesn't read the whole file when you initialize it: it reads it on demand. Thus, you need to still be inside the block when you read lines from the csv reader.

---

**Other Notes**

You've got a bunch of other problems. You seem to be unsure whether you're trying to clean three or four backslashes--make sure you know what you're doing before you try to do it!

Your actual row replacement is broken, because as you've written it, `allRows` is a list, not a string, so you're probably not going to find the backslash pattern you're looking for. Instead, you need an inner loop to look through each cell in each row:

```
for row in reader:
    corrected = []
    for cell in row:
        corrected.append(cell.replace('\\\\\\', '\\')) # Gross! See below.
    writer.writerow(corrected)
```

Note that I can't see where `writer` is defined, but it looks like it might be subject to the same problem as your reader, if it's defined in a context manager someplace else!

Finally, [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) are your friends (though they may not help you much here). In general, anytime you want a literal backslash in your strings, put an `r` in front of the string to save yourself a lot of headache. **However**, replacing odd numbers of backslashes is still a problem, because *even raw strings cannot end in an odd number of backslashes*.

So, to replace `\\\` with `\` (replace three backslashes with one), you'll have to double up on the backslashes like I did in the example above. If you wanted to replace four backslashes with two, you could use raw strings to your advantage: `cell.replace(r'\\\\', r'\\')` works just fine.

---

For posterity: you could also do something just as ugly, but in a different way, by adding a space to the end of the pattern strings so they no longer end with backslashes, and then stripping off the extra space. The following line replaces three backslashes with one, but it's much hackier (and slower if you're doing it a whole lot):

```
s = r'This is a \\\ string with \\\ sets \ of \\ three backslash\\\es.'
print(s.replace(r'\\\ '.strip(), r'\ '.strip()))
```

Answer (score 1):

The slashes you're trying to match are getting treated as escapes, so `'\\\\'` is actually looking for `'\\'`.

Try using raw strings, i.e. `r'\\\\'` (you'll want to use raw strings for both the matching as well as the replace).

You could also double up the slashes, so use `\\` everytime you want `\`, but that gets cumbersome very quickly

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
allRows.replace('\\\\\\', '\\')
```

Please note that the `\` symbols needs to be escaped, by doubling.

```
>>> d
'C:\\\\\\Users\\\\\\Simon\\\\\\Desktop\\\\\\file.jpg\n'
>>> d.replace('\\\\\\', '\\')
'C:\\Users\\Simon\\Desktop\\file.jpg\n'
>>> print d.replace('\\\\\\', '\\')
C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\file.jpg
```

Comment: While this should work, it's not good advice; raw strings make everything a lot easier to read. And the OP's whole problem seems to be that there are too many slashes for him to count properly, so that's pretty important here…